# Xcode 11 apple distribution accepted but impossible to build with flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile

I renewed my 1 year apple development and renewed my certificate

```
> Xcode 11 supports the new Apple Development and Apple Distribution certificate types. These certificates support building, running, and
> distributing apps on any Apple platform. Preexisting iOS and macOS
> development and distribution certificates continue to work, however,
> new certificates you create in Xcode 11 use the new types. Previous
> versions of Xcode don’t support these certificates. (45527608)
```

Due to this note for Xcode11, I test to create an Apple distribution instead of iOS distribution like before

So, I create this and select the good provisioning profileee in Xcode.

At this step, all is good.

but now when I try to run app

I have

```
No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your 
device. You can create a new Provisioning Profile for your project in Xcode for 
your team by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     - For Xcode 10, look under General > Signing > Team.
     - For Xcode 11 and newer, look under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle 
Identifier was signed with a different certificate.
```

But my provisioning profile is well accepted in Xcode in signing & capabilities, team is well selected, I'm well connected with my Apple ID

when it's write :

```
"It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle 
Identifier was signed with a different certificate."
```

I think it's the case, because I renew my 1 year account, and renew my certificate. I don't understand what is the problem

I well selected my physical device
I try flutter clean, xcode build clean

If I use automatically manage signing, Xcode select a iOS developpement profile type, so I can build and run my app, but If I select manually my Apple distribution it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling app from device and rebuilding? Also flutter `clean`

Comment: I will delete this post because my solution was to create new projet. Now I can build. Don’t understand ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Close Xcode, then clean derived data:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Open Xcode Clean and Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

> It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle
> Identifier was signed with a different certificate.

If it's a different certificate then you need to trust that **new** developer certificate on your physical device.

See steps from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477):

If you want to turn on SSL trust for that certificate, go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings. Under "Enable full trust for root certificates," turn on trust for the certificate.

[image]